# Understanding Linux directory permissions reasoning

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, directory

Hi I have 2 questions regarding linux directory permissions which I do not understand.

I removed the execute flag from a folder named Documents. After that I cannot use cd on it but I still can do "ls Documents" from the parent directory and it still lists me the files in the Documents directory. 
I though the missing x-flag denies reading this directory?

Then I want to know for why the sticky bit on directories was invented. I've heard it was used so that users cannot delete temp-files creates by other users. But this IMO violates the rule that for deletion of files we just need rights for this directory. Why not simply give each user a separate /tmp/ directory instead of introducing exceptions in the rule system? 
I know what the flag does, but I want to know the reasoning on why is was invented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Execute bit:** The execute bit is needed to **traverse** a directory. Permission to **read** a directory is controlled by the read bit.

See this shell dialogue for an example of this difference:

As root:

```
# find foo/ -ls
drwxr-xr--   3 root     root         4096 Apr 27 12:57 foo/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Apr 27 12:57 foo/bar
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root            0 Apr 27 12:57 foo/bar/file
```

as user:

```
$ ls foo/
bar
$ find foo/ -ls
drwxr-xr--   3 root     root         4096 Apr 27 12:57 foo/
find: foo/: Permission denied
$
```

The usual usage is the other way round though: removing read permissions but allowing traversal, e.g. to allow a web server into ~/public_html but not letting it do the default index listing by setting `--x`.

**Sticky bit:** This was invented exactly to avoid the default rules about deletion within a directory so `/tmp` works. `/tmp` might reside on a different volume than `/home` and/or be governed by different quotas.

The [FHS codifies /tmp](http://proton.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES) "for programs that require temporary files" while "[they] must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are preserved between invocations".

Personally, I consider /tmp to be legacy from the heathen days when `vi globals.h && make install` was considered an installation procedure. Nowadays programs should honour `$TMPDIR`, which should point to a user-private system-managed directory, which should be cleaned at least on reboot. Even standardised functions like [tmpfile(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile) do not prescribe the actual path. Although there seem to be important [compatibility and security concerns speaking for /tmp](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/libc-alpha/1999-04/msg00075.html). Note though, that the last mail is from 1999, so things might have change since then.

Comment: X-bit: But if I can still read the files from a directory without x-bit why do I need it? Which operation forces me to actually change into this directory?

S-bit: sure, but you could create subdirs in the /tmp/ directory for each user. Maybe additionally create hardlinks like /home/otto/tmp/ -> /tmp/otto/ but it still would work well without.

Comment: I improved the answer hoping to address the points of your comment.

Comment: it may forbid actually "changing" is the directory but I can still do everything I could do before, so what is it actually good for? I still can do "ls foo/" and "ls foo/bar" even "cat foo/bar/file" still works fine. I also can delete the files in it. What is in your opinion the difference between traverse and read? If I can list all files in a dir and its subdirs then I theoretically can search for files in it. So why doesn't "find" work?

Comment: find doesn't work because it (presumably) tries to chdir into foo/, which is not allowed.

Comment: Not quite the answers I was hoping to get, but maybe nobody knows why they made this decision in the development of this operating system. Thank you very much anyway. I mark it as solved.

Answer (score 5):

Just stumbled across this because it's got a high Google search rating. The execute-bit issue hasn't really been answered, so...

If the execute bit isn't set on a directory, then it's not "traversable", which means that shells and file browsers should be designed to disallow you from setting that directory as current, although that feature can't be enforced by the file-system itself.  What the file-system *does* disallow on a no-execute directory is any information *other* than the filename of the contained files -- so no datestamps or file-permissions of those files, and no reading of those files even if they have read set.

Answer (score 3):

[Sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

The most common use of the sticky bit today is on directories, where, when set, items inside the directory can be renamed or deleted only by the item's owner, the directory's owner, or the superuser; without the sticky bit set, any user with write and execute permissions for the directory can rename or delete contained files, regardless of owner. Typically this is set on the /tmp directory to prevent ordinary users from deleting or moving other users' files. This feature was introduced in 4.3BSD in 1986 and today it is found in most modern Unix systems.

In addition, Solaris (as of Solaris 2.5) defines special behavior when the sticky bit is set on non-executable files: those files, when accessed, will not be cached by the kernel. This is usually set on swap files to prevent access on the file from flushing more important data from the system cache. It is also used occasionally for benchmarking tests.

The sticky bit is also set by the automounter to indicate that a file has not been mounted yet. This allows programs like ls to ignore unmounted remote files.

Comment: as I said I already know what it's good for but I wanted to know why they used the other/cleaner solution I proposed. Imo the sticky bit is just a workaround for a messed up directory structure.

Comment: It is called 'legacy behaviour'; it prevented the scripts written that assumed /tmp was OK from breaking.

Answer (score 0):

For a CD directories should be mode 0555 and files 0444.
The Unix group can be thought of as a role.
Your roles are your supplementary groups.
The controls are mandatory if you not the owner.
They are discretionary if you are.
You can only traverse the path if you have eXecute/search permission of each path element. This differs to Microsoft Windows which is vulnerable to directory traversal.
It was invented to implement the Rainbow Series
"DoD Trusted Computer System Evaluation Criteria".